# Applying animation delay causing elements to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have the following very simple jQuery/SVG animation, its basically a bounceIn animation , the JS code looks as follows:

```
$(function(){

    var i = 0;
    $('svg .magnify').css({ 'opacity' : 0 });

    setTimeout(function(){
            $('svg .magnify').each(function(){

                //$(this).css({'animation-delay' : ((i < 200 ? (i += 200) : i = 200) + 's' ) });
                $(this)[0].classList.add('bounce-mg');

            });

    }, 2000);

});
```

See the FIDDLE **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/kbprvswk/3/)**, the animation runs perfectly , but now i want to add a delay to one of the elements , if i add the animation delay in CSS , it works fine, but i want to add the animation delay in jQuery and so i have the following line of code:

```
$(this).css({'animation-delay' : ((i < 200 ? (i += 200) : i = 200) + 's' ) });
```

*(I have commented out the above line of code in the fiddle.)*

Now , the above line of code does't allow my animation to complete or makes the elements disappear, can somebody tell me why this is happening ? why is applying the animation delay via jQuery causing the elements to disappear ?

Thank you.

Comment: It works but do you really want a 200 second delay? I tried after reducing the delay to 25s for testing and the magnifying glass like icon did appear after 25s.

Comment: @Harry thanks , no i want a 1/5 of a secound delay , which i think is equivalent to 200 or did i get my math wrong ?

Comment: Then you probably want a `ms` to be added and not a `s` :)

Comment: I am not planning on adding an answer as it is more like a typo error. Please go ahead and delete the question if you wish to (I don't think you'd be near any question ban). Or, it will most likely get closed. Happy New Year :)